# Heroku build error "Extracting tar content of undefined failed"

Tags: node.js, heroku, yarnpkg

I have a react-nodejs app which builds fine locally but when pushing to Heroku it returns an error:

```
remote:        error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@privacyresearch/libsignal-protocol-protobuf-ts/-/libsignal-protocol-protobuf-ts-0.0.8.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/yarncache.96jam/v6/npm-@privacyresearch-libsignal-protocol-protobuf-ts-0.0.8-5f8c6f70b1f50805b06fa38d81c0994f82e8562f-integrity/node_modules/@privacyresearch/libsignal-protocol-protobuf-ts/LICENSE'"
```

Here's my [package.json](https://github.com/haochenuw/signal-demo/blob/main/package.json) file.

I read through several related questions and it seems like the root cause might be related to having a github url in the package.json. Given that it is also a hard dependency for me, I don't know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6312

Answer (score 9):

Try `yarn install --network-concurrency 1`

And try adding a .yarnrc file to the project with following line: network-concurrency 1

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the only option I could install my deps inside a docker container, while on the host, everything works as expected. Is there any explanation for it? For me, this still looks like a small workaround

Comment: You can check this issue https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2457 @Ercksen

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue recently in setting up a new project without `yarn.lock` file.

I tried clearing the yarn cache using the command :-

`yarn cache clean`

but the same error still occurred.

Then I used the following command and it got solved :-

`yarn install --force --network-timeout 1000000`